# Is there a way to have a conditional transpose in SAS?

Tags: sas

I need to make my transpose conditional. A flow I'm creating in EG allows you to turn some sections of the flow off. It does this by using a macro variable (e.g. &myvariable). When &myvariable is set to 0, that section of the flow will be filtered out, so effectively, no rows of data pass through that section.

This works great, but stacks/ transposes will not work when there is no data.

I need it so that when there is no data to go into the transpose, it instead just makes a padded column to replicate what would have been the output of that program.

It needs to be in base SAS, I'm using Enterprise Guide. I've already tried using the conditional logic functionality in EG, but it's not appropriate because I need an ordered list.

```
''' some conditional logic?

if &myvariable = 0 then do;
   format padded_col1 $10.;

else do;

'''transpose 
proc transpose data= some_dataset;
    by id;
    id year;
    var income;
run;
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use macro logic, not data step here, if you have SAS 9.4+ you can use %IF/%THEN in open code. If you don't you need to wrap it in a macro.

```
%if &myVariable = 0 %then %do;
    *****sas code*******
%end;

%else %do;
     ****conditional proc transpose***** 
%end;
```